# How can I use StaticRouter inside renderToString in typescript ssr?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering, render-to-string

This is what I currently have

```
export const renderer = () => {
  const content = renderToString(React.createElement(Home));
  return ` <html> 
    <head>
   
    </head>
    <body>
    <div  id="root">${content}</div>
    <script></script>
    <script src="main-bundle.js"> </script>
    </body></html> `;
};
```

I created a Routes file, I need to wrap it with StaticRouter and ship it to the browser. However I cannot pass it like this:

```
<StaticRouter>
  <Routes />
</StaticRouter>
```

In the client side for BrowserRouter, I created an app component and rendered this app.

```
export const app: React.FC<appProps> = ({}) => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

inside client.tsx

```
   ReactDOM.hydrate(React.createElement(app), document.getElementById("root"));
```

I could not figure out it in server side. The only thing I am thinking is to create a component like app.tsx, instead of BrowserRouter using StaticRouter but I don't think that creating a react component component on the server is the right way.

Currently I am processing with this but that is not the proper way neither:

```
const routes = React.createElement(Routes, {}, "");
const router = React.createElement(StaticRouter, {}, routes);
```

[image]

Comment: If you would like just create a codesandbox with the whole configuration that way we can have a bigger picture of the problem and proceed with giving you a solution on that same plateform. Ping me up if you decide to do so.

Answer (score 0):

That pattern is absolutely correct!

I.e. define an `<App>` component containing your routes, then wrap it with the appropriate router implementation provider on server and client, as you suggest.

I think the way to think about it is similar to dependency injection. You have all your actual app logic encapsulated in `<App>` - the `<BrowserRouter>` or `<StaticRouter>` is just a provider, an implementation detail.

It doesn't change how `<App>` behaves, it just applies the appropriate implementation to make routing work in the environment you're running in.